# How to use QFileDialog to allow open only certain suffix?

Tags: c++, qt

What if i want to make program that works only with csv files for example. 
Is there a way of using QFileDialog to not allow opening files with any other suffix expect csv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fourth argument is the filter:

```
fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"), "/", tr("CSV Files (*.csv)"));
```